# Is it possible to set up token based authorization without creating specific scopes for applications?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-active-directory, authorization

I am using Oauth2 Authorization code from with PKCE to authorize a Single Page Application to a Backend API. I am using Azure as my Identity Provider, a .NET backend and MSAL.js library for the client.

Every tutorial asks me to create a basic "access_as_user" scope for my backend application.

Is it possible to omit that or are scopes something required by the OAuth2 standard and one has to have at least 1?

Answer (score 1):

Scopes are a part of the OAuth standard, though how much you use them is up to you. For some further details see the [Scope Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/) article.

Azure AD has some vendor specific extensions, which will require you to expose at least one custom scope from the API in order to get a usable access token. See [step 6 of my blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/01/azure-ad-spa-code-sample/) for how this looks.

In the early days you may want your SPA to express scope values such as this. It is standard for clients to use a mix of built-in and custom scopes:

```
openid profile api://cb398b43-96e8-48e6-8e8e-b168d5816c0e/transactions_read"
```